# EditText: Crash onLongPress, onDoubleCheck on Samsung Device Only

Tags: android, android-edittext, samsung-mobile

For any `onLongPress` / `onDoubleClick` in the **EditText** for **Samsung Devices**, the app will just crash. However, **the problem will not happen in other devices**. I am using my old Note 2 for debugging and see similar issue posted in the forum (but has been deleted). Great if anyone would share the solutions.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/vse_discountEv"
    android:hint="@string/vse_boradcastHint"            
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/pad_3dp"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/pad_5dp"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/pad_0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/pad_5dp"              
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:textColorHint="@color/gray_main_light"
    android:textSize="@dimen/dim_20dp"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal" />
```

Logcat Message:

```
10-28 11:08:56.311: E/AndroidRuntime(22228): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-28 11:08:56.311: E/AndroidRuntime(22228): Process: com.export, PID: 22228
10-28 11:08:56.311: **E/AndroidRuntime(22228): java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero**
10-28 11:08:56.311: E/AndroidRuntime(22228):    at android.widget.Editor.updateShowAsAction(Editor.java:6111)
10-28 11:08:56.311: E/AndroidRuntime(22228):    at android.widget.Editor$SelectionActionModeCallback.onCreateActionMode(Editor.java:3314)
10-28 11:08:56.311: E/AndroidRuntime(22228):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView$ActionModeCallbackWrapper.onCreateActionMode(PhoneWindow.java:3020)
10-28 11:08:56.311: E/AndroidRuntime(22228):    at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl$ActionModeImpl.dispatchOnCreate(ActionBarImpl.java:1021)
10-28 11:08:56.311: E/AndroidRuntime(22228):    at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.startActionMode(ActionBarImpl.java:550)
10-28 11:08:56.311: E/AndroidRuntime(22228):    at android.app.Activity.onWindowStartingActionMode(Activity.java:5218)
10-28 11:08:56.311: E/AndroidRuntime(22228):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.startActionMode(PhoneWindow.java:2632)
10-28 11:08:56.311: E/AndroidRuntime(22228):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.startActionModeForChild(PhoneWindow.java:2619)
10-28 11:08:56.311: E/AndroidRuntime(22228):    at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:675)
10-28 11:08:56.311: E/AndroidRuntime(22228):    at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:675)
10-28 11:08:56.311: E/AndroidRuntime(22228):    at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:675)
10-28 11:08:56.311: E/AndroidRuntime(22228):    at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:675)
10-28 11:08:56.311: E/AndroidRuntime(22228):    at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:675)
10-28 11:08:56.311: E/AndroidRuntime(22228):    at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:675)
10-28 11:08:56.311: E/AndroidRuntime(22228):    at android.view.View.startActionMode(View.java:4752)
10-28 11:08:56.311: E/AndroidRuntime(22228):    at android.widget.Editor.startSelectionActionMode(Editor.java:1814)
10-28 11:08:56.311: E/AndroidRuntime(22228):    at android.widget.Editor.performLongClick(Editor.java:1045)
10-28 11:08:56.311: E/AndroidRuntime(22228):    at android.widget.TextView.performLongClick(TextView.java:10118)
10-28 11:08:56.311: E/AndroidRuntime(22228):    at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:19410)
10-28 11:08:56.311: E/AndroidRuntime(22228):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
10-28 11:08:56.311: E/AndroidRuntime(22228):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-28 11:08:56.311: E/AndroidRuntime(22228):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
10-28 11:08:56.311: E/AndroidRuntime(22228):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
10-28 11:08:56.311: E/AndroidRuntime(22228):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-28 11:08:56.311: E/AndroidRuntime(22228):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-28 11:08:56.311: E/AndroidRuntime(22228):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
10-28 11:08:56.311: E/AndroidRuntime(22228):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
10-28 11:08:56.311: E/AndroidRuntime(22228):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What does Logcat say?

Comment: Post the error please what is there in logcat

Comment: I updated the msg from logcat. It said divide by zero....but the edittext longpress is functing well in other devices

Comment: @AntoineMurion are you able to solved the issue? I am facing the same issue here is my question link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49109393/appcompatedittext-gets-crashed-on-os-lollipop-and-below-version

Comment: Hi, I am having the same problem, did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

How did you handle `onLongPress` and `onDoubleClick` in your code?

I have tested the following code in another **Samsung devices** (SM-A7009), could not find the issue you described unfortunately.

I use `GestureDetector` to handle `onLongPress` and `onDoubleClick` event.

```
  EditText editText1 = new EditText(this);
  editText1.setText(R.string.app_name);
  final GestureDetectorCompat gestureDetectorCompat = new GestureDetectorCompat(this,
            new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                    super.onLongPress(e);
                    Log.d(TAG, "onLongPress");
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onDoubleTap");
                    return super.onDoubleTap(e);
                }
            });
  editText1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
          return gestureDetectorCompat.onTouchEvent(event);
      }
  });
  setContentView(editText1);
```

Comment: It is just an edittext with no special handling. But longpress is needed in this edittext as the user will longpress to copy the text from the edittext. 
I tried your code on Samsung Note2, it doesn't crash but it is no longer editable and onlongpress it would not highlight the text/words for copy.